# Outlook 2007 Addin Locking Outlook Accessing a deleted Exchange User

Tags: c#, exchange-server, outlook-addin, outlook-2007

I have an Outlook 2007 add-in that adds information to calendar items.  I'm running into a problem where if an old Calendar Invite is opened containing Exchange users that are no longer valid, Outlook hangs for around 90 seconds trying to lookup the contact. (Outlook is running in Cached Mode in this case)

I'm trying to figure out if there's a way to access an Exchange user's email asynchronously, or to detect that the user is removed, and simply skip it.  Basically, anything to stop the UI from hanging for a whole minute and a half.

```
AddressEntry ae = appointmentItem.Recipients[0];
ExchangeUser eu = ae.GetExchangeUser();//hangs here if user is not in cached address book
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd try to use the Redemption library with RDO to access the property and see how it reacts in this case.
See http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/ and look for "RDORecipients object collection".

Comment: We were using redemption on our 2003 client.  I was kind of trying to avoid it because of the size it adds to the package.

Comment: All I really need to access is the email address of the recipients.  Is there a way to use "part of" redemption, or to just access the email addresses of the recipients without accessing the exchange user?  One other option I'm considering is try and make Exchange connect in the background - instead of waiting until the first contact is accessed.

Answer (score 0):

Redemption is never a bad idea - it's a very good library.

Another option is to call the GetExchangeuser() on another thread. This would avoid the blocking. Of course, you need to figure what to do in this case - show a "Please wait" dialog or let the user do something else during the duration of the call.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I had this thought but my main concern is that this would qualify as "accessing the outlook object model on another thread", which I've read in numerous places can cause hangups and crashing of outlook.

Comment: This is absolutely right. You may use threading to talk to other resources, e.g. a database which has no connection with Outlook directly, but to interact with Outlook in threads is not recommended. Additionally you want to do this on opening an Outlook item, so I'm afraid that this would work.